# Calling functions from within another - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, fabricjs

I'm relatively new to javascript and having a couple of issues that I'm hoping you can help with.  I'm utilizing the fabric library with canvas to create an animation of sorts.

I have a function that is called when the relevant button is pressed:

```
//for starting the animation
startSim.onclick = function(){

    //obtain speed value from the control panel.
    var speed = 10000 / (new Number(speedControl.value));
    //stuff
    //animation process
        object.animate('top', '+='+canvas.height,{
            duration: speed,
            abort: function(){
                var returnedBool;
                //Pause is pressed, simulation pauses
                if(pause){
                 //stuff
                }
                //restart required
                if(restart){
                    //stuff
                }
                //option here to save data?
                return returnedBool;
            },//end abort callback

            onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
            onComplete: function(){
                //stuff
            }
        });//end animate callback
};
```

What I'd like to do is call certain other functions while the above animation is active.

I know how I'd like to do this using Java or C++ but I can't seem to call the function.

I have a display panel that should output various information - as the animation completes variables will change and I'd like them to be output on the screen and be updated as they change.

I'm testing with a simple function:

```
    function updateInfoPanel(testSpeed){
    var test = document.getElementById('currentSpeed');
    test.innerHTML = test.innerHTML + testSpeed;
}
```

I think I need to call this in the main animate loop, if I call it before it's fine but obviously only displays the variable once.  Could someone tell me where I'm going wrong please?

I also have a basic collision detection function that works but not within the animate loop and I think these problems are linked.

Many thanks for any help.

I removed the unnecessary parts of the code to save space.

So I've just tried to use a function as the result of onChange:

```
onChange: function(){
                canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas);
                updateInfoPanel(speed);
            },
```

This doesn't present syntax errors but the animation no lingers runs although the speed variable does update in the info panel very quickly. :(

Comment: I may be mistaken but could you simply put your update functions in that `onChange` event?

Comment: Hi @Robb, I tried that but it doesn't seem to like it.  Expects a colon but I can't give it one.

Comment: @Robb - Hi again, updated question a touch as it feels like I'm getting closer.

Comment: In the onChange event it probably doesn't know what `canvas` is inside the callback so the render doesn't work. That would be my first guess as to why it isn't updating.

Comment: @Robb - makes sense.  It's doesn't throw up any errors though but you're right, there is no rendering.  I've tried passing the canvas as a param but that fails.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What library are you using for this or is this something you've down on your own?

Comment: @Robb Using the fabric library.  It's great but support is not as easy to come by

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43145/discussion-between-robb-and-steve-green)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to **call** renderAll(), bind is actually returning a function to be used as a handler. Just try this code:

```
onChange: function(){
                canvas.renderAll();//.bind(canvas);
                updateInfoPanel(speed);
            },
```

And let me know if it helped?

Comment: marry me.  Tonight, I can sleep.

Comment: thanks arty, have you used the fabric library at all?

Comment: yes, i had. we may continue to chat here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43312/20573801-arty-steve